# django auto complete light says field is required on ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light

I have two models:

```
class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    '''
    Product Category determines to which category the product falls into.
    '''

    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=254)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" %(self.category_name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Product Categories"



class Product(models.Model):
    '''
    Product Information
    '''
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory)



def __unicode__(self):
    return u"%s" %(self.product_name)
```

I want to apply `autocomplete` on category `field` of product model. Thus,

```
class ProductCategoryAutoComplete(autocomplete_light.AutocompleteModelBase):
    search_fields = ['category_name']
    model = Product
    choices = ProductCategory.objects.all()

autocomplete_light.register(Product, ProductCategoryAutoComplete)
```

I have included the template too. Everything works fine. Except when I choose the category and submit the form `html` field is required is popping up in the bottom. What is wrong?

**Edit: Form**

```
class ProductCreateForm(autocomplete_light.ModelForm):
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ProductCategory.objects, widget=autocomplete_light.ChoiceWidget('ProductCategoryAutoComplete'))
    class Meta:
        model = Product
```

Comment: Could you paste your form ?

Comment: Updated question with form. Thanks so much for the great library :)

Answer (score 2):

### Oops !

`Product.category` is an FK to model `Category`, but the Autocomplete you are passing (`ProductCategoryAutoComplete`) is registered for `Product` model ! Field that should allow selecting a `Category` should use an autocomplete for `Category`, not one for `Product` ;)

### Better usage of `autocomplete_light.ModelForm`

Since you're using `autocomplete_light.ModelForm`, you don't have to specify the field. Just register an autocomplete for `Category`:

```
autocomplete_light.register(Category, search_fields=['category_name'])
```

And let `autocomplete_light.ModelForm` do the field definition:

```
class ProductCreateForm(autocomplete_light.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
```

Yes, that's **all** you need ;)

Comment: I followed the exact same way you suggested but the lookup is not shown on the category field of product table. The typical drop down of foreign key is shown. Then I used `CategoryAutoComplete` on the form which gives the same error. `field required`

Comment: I dig with the firebug. The option value is also added but the textbox which is hide after selecting the required value has no value and says field is required.

Answer (score 0):

`search_fields` is wrong, product does`n have field category_name, if I understand your idea it have to be:

```
class ProductCategoryAutoComplete(autocomplete_light.AutocompleteModelBase):
    search_fields = ['category__category_name']
    model = Product
    choices = ProductCategory.objects.all()

autocomplete_light.register(Product, ProductCategoryAutoComplete)
```

Comment: Tried that but it turns out `autolookup` is redirectly looking at `ProductCategory` table. I receive `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'category' into field. Choices are: category_name, description, id`

Comment: what is `autolookup` ?